# SQL Query from multiple schems in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, vba

I have a list of 5 Access database files, all the files have the same tables and relations but they contain different data.

I'm writing my app in VB.NET and I need to execute a query in VB (it's a simple one, not something special) that gives me the data from all the Access files.

Is there is a way to do this? All the files are on a single server.

Currently I am the only user and I have all permissions .

Assume I have:

```
 db1
 db2
 db3
  .
  .
 db_n
```

and all the dbs have the same tables.

**I want to execute**

```
select * from mytbl where mytbl.id >20 ;
```

**I need to see all the data of this query from all the db's.**

Comment: Yes that is possible. That's as much as we can tell you without some schema, sample data, and maybe an attempt. :)

Comment: Hello Moti, welcome to SO! We understand that you need help but it would be better if you show us what have you tried so far. It would be easier for us. It's like _helping us to help you_. Have a nice day.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: im sorry i new here,

Comment: the data are classify because it contain צedical Information of real users\

Comment: Then make a small, testable, version you can try with and share.

Answer (score 0):

An option may be to link the external tables using External Data --> Import Access Database, then creating the query internally to your current APP. Then, your SQL query would be a standard query within the db would look something like:

Assuming tables are mytbl, dbo_mytbl, and dbo_mytbl1

```
SELECT mytbl.id
FROM (mytbl INNER JOIN dbo_mytbl ON mytbl.Id = dbo_mytbl.Id) INNER JOIN dbo_mytbl1 ON dbo_mytbl.Id = dbo_mytbl1.Id
WHERE (((mytbl.Id)>20));
```